# Django Use ManyToManyField Data in View

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, blank = False)
    extra_profile_text = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)
    extra_category_text = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)

class ProfileCategory(models.Model):
    profile = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileCategory
        fields = ('profile', 'category',)
```

views.py

```
def task(request): 

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileCategoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user

            #use [profile_name, extra_category_text data] that user selected

            post.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('somewhere')
    else:
        form = ProfileCategoryForm()
    context = {'form': form }
    return render(request, 'some_app/somewhere.html', context)
```

I want to bring 'profile_name', 'extra_category_text' datas in view when user select from ProfileCategoryForm.
process will be 
Front: user select one of Profile, one of Category > Save
Back: get user selected Profile, Category datas(ex: profile_name, extra_profile_text) > do some task > Save to ProfileCategory model.

it seems that I need to use queryset but no clue at all :(

Comment: One question: Why have you used `ManyToManyField` fields in `ProfileCategory` to link `Profile` and `Category` instead of using `ForeignKey` fields to `Profile`  and `Category`?

Answer (score 0):

Like @gitblame said, you create such a complicate models.
You can change the model to easier query.

Front: user select one of Profile, one of Category > Save

We do it normally, return data to html, show it and take care of it.

```
# You can create js file and capture event of class/id changed and request to api server 
#(if you want to check like: 1 Profile and can select only Category relate only)
```

Back: get user selected Profile, Category datas(ex: profile_name, extra_profile_text) > do some task > Save to ProfileCategory model.

> You can do it like, **check when the form submit to views.py** or **check in model** (override the save method, anything else...)

link to django [override method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)